# Retrieve items from a MySQL database BUT with some mathematical rules first

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table on my MySQL server:

```
id      name    url     type    ut      lastcheck
1       Name1   url1    1       5       2011-06-28 12:21:46
2       Name2   url2    1       10      2011-06-28 12:21:46
3       Name3   url3    1       12      2011-06-28 12:21:46
4       Name4   url4    1       1       2011-06-28 12:21:46
```

**ut** means *update time*, in minutes. I want to develop a script using MySQL commands that retrieves me only the elements that complains this statement:

**NOW()** - **lastcheck**=>**ut**

I'm developing in php and I know how to do this retrieving **all** the elements and then using simple php operations to filter the elements I need, BUT I don't want any more load in my script. So I want my MySQL server to do all the work but I have no idea how to build the SQL query to do this.

I know that MYSQL can make difference between dates using `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '2010-11-26 12:00:00');` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you need to select the rows where the number of minutes since the last check is greater than ut?

You should be able to use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` command for that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ut < TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,lastcheck,NOW());
```

The `TIMESTAMPDIFF` command allows you to specify the units that you wish to be output so it should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: **Retrieving**, not deleting!

Comment: Ah, updated accordingly (Thought I read `remove` not `retrieve`!!) @ypercube Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on `ut`, this may benefit from the index:

```
WHERE ut <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, lastcheck, NOW())
```

If you have an index on `lastcheck`, this may benefit from the index:

```
WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL ut MINUTE) >= lastcheck
```

---

Thinking more clearly, I don't think any of the two versions can beneficially use any index at all.

The second perhaps (if the distinct values in `ut` are few compared to the rows of the table) would benefit from a JOIN to an auxilary table.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT 
          ut 
        , (NOW() - INTERVAL ut MINUTE) AS nowMinusInterval 
      FROM table
      GROUP BY ut
    ) AS dt
  ON t.ut = dt.ut
WHERE dt.nowMinusInterval >= t.lastcheck
```